# Is it possible to post a link that targets a specific choice in an accordeon so to open automatically?

Tags: hyperlink, mootools, joomla2.5, accordion

I have a page that contains multiple topics in accordion.
How can I post a link (on social media or other places) so when the user clicks it can view the topic I want without making him choose the desired one to view it?

The website is built in Joomla 2.5 using its native (mootools) accordions.

A temporary solution came to my mind is to make single pages containing only the content I want, but it won't help them view the other topics contained in the same page, unless the user clicks the same category.

Comment: Do you mean that by clicking a link one specific part of the accordion would open?

Comment: I mean that if I share with you this link through facebook for example, you should be able to see the specific part of accordion open. Other parts should be closed of course.. Haven't looked for a solution since then, but this sounds to me now as I need an extension or a workaround..

Comment: Posted an answer for you. Was that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MooAccordion has a display option. You could use like:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    var index = window.location.search; // get query string
    index = index.replace("?", '');     // remove the ?
    index = index.length ? index : 0;   // in case there in no query, display first
    var myAccordion = new Fx.Accordion($('accordion'), '#accordion h2', '#accordion .content', {
        display: index // the actual behavior you are looking for
    });
});
```

Read more at [**Mootools docs**](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Accordion#)

So you could try these links as demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/brM2v/show/?0
http://jsfiddle.net/brM2v/show/?1
http://jsfiddle.net/brM2v/show/?2

Comment: Seems what I need but I ve trouble to implement it. I entered this chunk in the code, altered the ids and classes, but it still doesn't work. Should the link be the url with /?x added? (where x the number of tab I m interested at. Target page: http://bit.ly/1aPOihF

Comment: @YannisDran, I didn't see the part of the code I posted here in your page, with the url variable... and neither saw the `display:` option in your accordion. Did you try that?

Comment: I removed it as I thought it caused problems loading the map. I put it back again. Try it once more please. http://bit.ly/1jtaGSZ
edit: it actually causes some strange behaviors.

Comment: @YannisDran, you have code for 2 Accordions. Is it the one in the middle of the page? Inside the `#sliders` ?

Comment: probably you mean the code in the head and the code towards the end before the </body> tag. Mine is the second one.

Comment: @YannisDran, the code you added near the end of body has wrong elements/classes. Its looking for a `contact-slide` ID and there is none in the page...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46035/discussion-between-yannis-dran-and-sergio)